# Checking the status of a ZFS pool

Tags: file-system, bash, linux, shell

I'd like to see if there are any suggestions on how to improve a simple conditional test at the beginning of a backup script that verifies a ZFS volume is "online" and has the name "tank".

For example:

```
% zpool list
NAME      SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  54.5T  36.0T  18.5T         -    35%    66%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

The following simple script works, but I suspect there may be a more elegant way to do this. ShellCheck notes $STATUS is unused...

```
#!/bin/sh
#
STATUS=$(/sbin/zpool list | grep tank | grep ONLINE)
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "Problems"
        exit 1
else

echo all system go!
exit 0

fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the `zpool` command, by specifying the volume name as an argument:

```
/sbin/zpool list tank | grep ONLINE
```

This will avoid cases where `tank` might be part of another volume's name. Better yet, use `zpool get`:

```
/sbin/zpool get -H health tank
```

This returns output which is more specific and easier to parse, since the status is the third, tab-separated field:

```
tank     health    ONLINE   -
```

So:

```
STATUS=$(/sbin/zpool get -H health tank | awk '{print $3}')
```

Then, you probably should test the value of `STATUS`, instead of the exit code:

```
if [ "$STATUS" != ONLINE ]; then
        echo "Problems"
        exit 1
...
```

Next, be consistent in indentation:

```
if [ "$STATUS" != ONLINE ]; then
        echo "Problems"
        exit 1
else
        echo "All systems go!"
        exit 0
fi
```

Also: `all system go!` should be `All systems go!`.

`exit 0` is unnecessary in this case, without it, the shell will exit the `else` block and then the script itself, and return the exit status of the last command executed (`echo`, which would return 0 unless it couldn't write output, in which case you probably shouldn't have the `echo` there anyway).